# cmd needs ".exe" to run programs

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Windows 7, cmd:

```
C:\>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>python.exe
(works)

C:\>bash
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\>bash.exe
(works)
```

etc...

Is there a way to make e.g. python.exe run when I type "python"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `.exe` is in your `%PATHEXT%`:

```
C:\>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.py;.pl
```

When you run `python`, Windows tries all extensions listed in that environment variable.

```
C:\>set pathext=.exe;%pathext%
```

Comment: simple and kewl :)